# Cross validation and model selection

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I am using `sklearn` for SVM training. I am using the cross-validation to evaluate the estimator and avoid the overfitting model.

I split the data into two parts. Train data and test data. Here is the code:

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn import cross_validation
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn import svm

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(
    iris.data, iris.target, test_size=0.4, random_state=0
)
clf = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C=1)
scores = cross_validation.cross_val_score(clf, X_train, y_train, cv=5)
print scores
```

Now I need to evaluate the estimator *clf* on X_test.

```
clf.score(X_test, y_test)
```

here,  I get an error saying that

```
the model is not fitted using fit()
```

but normally, in `cross_val_score` function the model is fitted? What is the problem?

Comment: When doing cross-validation you would train your model on `X_train`, `y_train`, then evaluate its performance on `X_test`, `y_test`. It wouldn't make sense to evaluate the performance of your classifier without training it first.

Comment: @ali_m, What cross_validation.cross_val_score() does? Normally it train the mode first. I see and understand very well what are you saying. For my case, I need a kind of early stopping to avoid the overfitting. I split the dataset onto 3 parts for examples train, valid, test. I train the model on the train part after that I tune it  on valid part. Once I obtain a reasonable train and valid error. I test it on test part. That is it!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`cross_val_score`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.cross_val_score.html#sklearn.cross_validation.cross_val_score) is basically a convenience wrapper for the sklearn [cross-validation iterators](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#cross-validation-iterators). You give it a classifier and your whole (training + validation) dataset and it automatically performs one or more rounds of cross-validation by splitting your data into random training/validation sets, fitting the training set, and computing the score on the validation set. See the documentation [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#computing-cross-validated-metrics) for an example and more explanation.

The reason why `clf.score(X_test, y_test)` raises an exception is because `cross_val_score` performs the fitting on a *copy* of the estimator rather than the original (see the use of `clone(estimator)` in the source code [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py#L147-L149)). Because of this, `clf` remains unchanged outside of the function call, and is therefore not properly initialized when you call `clf.fit`.

Comment: Thanks, I see. But in this case if this function does not return the "good" estimator after evaluation with cross validation, what is its utility? Its utility is to waist time doing cross validation and after that we don't give the fitted model! However, if there is a way to clone the estimator, it will be important and having a sense.

Comment: The purpose of cross-validation is to estimate how well your classifier will perform on unseen examples. If you were to evaluate its performance directly on your training set then you would tend to get an unrealistically good score. *By itself*, cross-validation doesn't do *anything* to make your classifier perform better. However, you would often use the cross-validation scores as your performance metric when you are optimizing your learning strategy - for example by adjusting the meta-parameters of your classifier (such as `C` and `gamma` in the case of SVM).

Comment: Ok. I am agree with you. But how to return these best parameters after cross-validation if this function works on a copy of the classifier? On the Other hand, I know that validation-set is used in early stopping strategy to stop the training stage when attempt the minimum validation error.

Comment: I present my problem in other way. Suppose that I have two data set which having the same distribution but having different dimensions. Suppose that I need to do a pre-training on the big data set and after that I do just a tuning of parameters of the resulting classifier on the second data set which is more small.

Comment: There would be no point in returning any parameters - as I said, cross-validation by itself doesn't give you any *"best parameters"* - all it gives you is a more realistic score for your classifier. If you're talking about tuning meta-parameters then you would do something like this: 1) choose a value for your meta-parameter, let's say `C`, 2) fit your classifier to a random set of training examples, 3), evaluate your classifier on the held-out test examples, 4) repeat this process for each value of `C` you want to test, 5) pick the value of `C` that gave you the best cross-validation score.

Comment: Scikit-learn also has some convenience methods for performing meta-parameter optimization using cross-validation. Take a look at the documentation [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/grid_search.html#grid-search) for some examples.

Comment: What if some variables are categorical? Do they need to be transformed? I tried to implement it and I got this message: ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'medium'